# 'fold over itself' and 'the boundary of the paper'

Tags: sentence-meaning, reading-comprehension

I'm having trouble comprehending a problem statement (I'm assuming that the problem statement is clear). The first two sentences I can understand (I've added them for context) but the 3rd is giving me problems.

> You would like to mail some origami you have made to your mom.
>
> The price of mailing is dependent on the area of the envelope used to
>   mail it: the smaller the envelope area, the less cost to ship. You
>   cannot fold the origami shape to make it smaller. Of course, the
>   envelope you are shipping the origami in must be rectangular.
>
> Consider the vertices which represent the points along the boundary of
>   the paper in order, such that the edge of the paper may fold over
>   itself. Given the vertices describing the origami shape, what is the
>   area of the smallest envelope that you can use to mail the origami?

I'm confused as to what means for the 'edge of the paper to fold over itself' and what is meant by 'the boundary of the paper'.

I assume that fold over itself means to connect two opposite edges of paper and that along the boundary of the paper means along the edges of the paper but I still don't understand the sentence.

Comment: I'm confused by the question, it says the piece cannot be folded to make it smaller in part two, but it seems that is what they are asking you to do in the third part. Is there a picture that goes with the question?

Comment: @Doarn No picture given, I'm given a sample input and output (here is the [link](https://dmoj.ca/problem/origami) to the problem) but without any explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right the last paragraph is confusing.

What it is saying is that given your origami, whatever it is, there will be "points" or vertices.  For example, on a crane, there would be the wing tips, the head, the tail, the front and back of the body. The question is then: What is the smallest rectangle (envelope) you can fit this in?

[image]